# Redux-Toolkit Middleware custom: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am studying Redux-Toolkit studio, and in particular, I am approaching custom middleware.

Below I report the definition of my store within my classic application example:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {todosSlice} from '.. /features/todos/todosSlice';
import { filterStore } from '.. /features/todos/filterSlice';
import { myLog } from '.. /reduxtoolkitmiddlewarecustom/myLog';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todos: todosSlice.reducer,
  filter: filterStore.reducer
});
 
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(). concat(myLog), 
                                                                               
});
```

As you see in the store amount, the middleware "custom" defined in '.. /reduxtoolkitmiddlewarecustom/myLog';

The definition of middleware is as follows:

```
export const myLog = (store) => {
   
    console.log('Init myLog');
    return function myDispatch(next) { 
        return function myAction(action) { //action is the action received from the store.
            store.Dispatch({ type: 'INIT_MYLOG', payload: null });
            console.log(action);
            //return next(action);
        }
    }
 
};
```

Well, if I emit a Dispatch, I do not return next(action), is that the return I still get an error of "***Uncaught Rangeerror: Maximum call stack size exceeded***".

I thought I understood, but evidently, I don't. The only way to make the code work is, for example, to make a console.log
What am I tripping about?
If found the error, in general, if the middleware makes a Dispatch in the store, must a corresponding reducer/action creator exist?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

your middleware dispatches `INIT_MYLOG` on every action. and that dispatched `INIT_MYLOG` then triggers your middleware. and that then dispatches. an endless circle.

Solution? Don't dispatch in a middleware except if you do it as a reaction to one specific action.

Comment: Hi @phry, Thank you for your explanation, among other things, extremely clear. Basically, if I have not misunderstood, if I run a Dispatch inside a middleware, I have to filter for which actions I can run that Dispatch. Otherwise, I will run into an infinite loop for obvious reasons.
Therefore, can we say that the Dispatch within a middleware performs to pre-process the data before the initial action is performed? A further question, should the Dispatch in middleware forward an action creator, for example, defined in a createSlicer?
Thank you very much again.

Comment: I would generally never dispatch an action "just like that" in a middleware, but only if either a specific action comes in or if a state value has changed from one value to another. Why don't you just dispatch that action once after store creation in your normal application code? I assume that is what you want to do here? Just call `store.dispatch(action())` there.

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "forwarding an action creator" though.

Comment: In my very first idea that I made, about middleware, Forgive me the misconceptions of understanding, I might have this condition:
`return function myDispatch(next) { 
        return function myAction(action) {            
              if(action.type === 'todos/toggleCompletedTodo'){
                    store.dispatch({type:'foo', payload:{name:'Test'}});
            }
            return next(action);
        }
    }`
What I mean in `store.Dispatch({type:'foo'...})`
Shouldn’t it be a defined action in the store with its reducer?
I apologize again for the trivial questions.

Comment: You can both dispatch an action as a plain object or created by the action creator, although I would always prefer the action creator. Generally you won't have a lot of need to write middlewares at all nowadays though. Thunks are already enough for most applications.

Comment: Dear @phry,
I see that I have come across a real Redux guru! Thank you very much for clearing my thoughts.
I'm just starting to study the power of thunks!
I hope I can follow you and read your posts.
You were friendly and my best compliments!

Comment: H @phry,
we said that rarely in a middleware will you send actions but generally we will make operations on the current state. In general, however, we said it is possible to Dispatch events with action creators. But if I am not wrong you said it is possible to send a plain text action with store.Dispatch({type: '', payload: ''}) but in this case who will manage this action? Not having a reducer in my store (slice)? The management of this action will still be left to a middleware? Because, in this case I haven't a reducer in my store/slicer. Thank you.

Comment: If you want your action to have any effect, a reducer will have to act on it in the end. Of course you can use actions to trigger other actions, but in the end only a reducer can change your state. As I said, custom middleware are not very important nowadays. Most will be done just in thunks.

Comment: thank you so much!